# Flutter Web Bouncing Scroll Physics

Tags: flutter, web, flutter-layout, physics, flutter-web

I can't find any information about physics using Flutter web, I used SingleChildScrollView, but the physics only applied when you use the scrollbar. I want to get the same physics using the mousepad or the Mouse scroll.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```
 Scrollbar(
        thickness: 8,
        controller: _yourController,
        hoverThickness: 10,
        showTrackOnHover: true,
        isAlwaysShown: true,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          controller: _yourController,
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          child: MyChild(),
        )
    )
```